# Any known way to diagonalize the Hamiltonian of a charge particle in a EM field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, second-quantization

Consider the Hamiltonian of a free (charged) particle, i.e.,
$$
H = \frac{p^2}{2m}.
$$
This is easily "diagonalized" by wave functions $e^{ikx}$ (where I'm speaking loosely of diagonalization since $e^{ikx}$ are not eigenstates in the Hilbert space $L^2$. Of course, we could regularize the problem by considering the Hamiltonian on a finite lattice with periodic boundary condition so that wave functions are indeed eigenstate.)

If we were to add a EM field, then by minimal coupling, the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
H = \frac{1}{2m}(p-eA)^2 +e\varphi
$$
**Question**. Is there an analytic or operator-based solution (e.g., latter operators) of diagonalizing this minimally-coupled Hamiltonian (we can ignore $\varphi$ if that helps)? If this problem is not regularized, we could also think of [Peierls substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peierls_substitution) of a second-quantized hopping Hamiltonian on a finite lattice with periodic boundary conditions, i..e,
$$
H= \sum_{i,j} t_{ij} c_i^* \exp{(-iA_{ij})} c_j
$$

Answer (score 1):

For a uniform/constant magnetic field, this is problem of [Landau quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization). It is essentially harmonic oscillator, with a momentum-dependant shift in its energy eigenvalues, and therefore can be understood in terms of ladder operators.

For a generic $A$ and $\varphi$ I don't know if this is possible, but somehow I would doubt it would be doable generally (apart from special cases of interest for $A$ and $\varphi$).

Comment: Gauge transformation? Can’t we always have just $A$?

Comment: good point, I guess for general $A$